# Regex to look for html tags based on their classes, and extract their value

Tags: regex, html-parsing

I'm looking for a Regex to look for html tags based on their class name, and extract their value, for example:

```
<span class="myclass" id="myid">Hello world</span>
```

I need to extract - Hello world

I've tried doing that by my own but it seems to be more complicated than it looks

Some help? :)

Thanks!

Comment: @OP before you progress, read: http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/ and this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3000179

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 TLDR: don't parse HTML with regex

Comment: "it seems to be more complicated than it looks"  No truer words were ever spoken.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```js
var str = '<span class="myclass" id="myid">Hello world</span>'; 
var res = str.match("<([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*)\\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\\1>");
alert(res[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I really prefer use a HTML parser.
But, if it is really needed, you can try this https://regex101.com/r/xP5kG7/1

```
.+(?<="myclass")[^>]+>([^<]+).+
```

It will give you the desirable output.